# AngularJS: How to get location of the marker after dragging a map

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following CSS which shows marker on the map , user can drag a map like Uber now I want to get current location of the marker , I have added `style.css` , `DeliverCtrl.js` and `HTML` code so please can anybody help me ?

**style.css**

```
map{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow:visible;
}
map:after {
    width: 22px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -40px 0 0 -11px;
    background: url('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi_hdpi.png');
    background-size: 22px 40px; /* Since I used the HiDPI marker version this compensates for the 2x size */
    pointer-events: none; /* This disables clicks on the marker. Not fully supported by all major browsers, though */
}
```

**DeliverCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('Home').controller('DeliverCtrl',["$scope","$state", function($scope, $state, $ionicModal, MessageService, $stateParams) {

    function initialize() {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng($state.params.lat,$state.params.lng);

        $scope.mapOptions = {
        mapTypeControl: true,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: position
    };

};

$scope.createMarker = function(latLng)
{

    var map = $scope.map;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Current Location'
    });
};

$scope.mapCreated = function(map) {
    $scope.map = map;
};

initialize();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
}]);
```

I have created the map through this html

```
<map on-create="mapCreated(map)" mapoptions="mapOptions"></map>
```

Comment: do you mean user drag the marker? since when drag the map, the marker will keep the same address.

Comment: @Pengyy user can drag the map and keep the marker still when user stop dragging the map then i want to get the location of the marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the css code you provided, you are trying to show a marker image over the map, while showing the map beneath the marker.

In that case, what you probably want is to get the center of the map, after dragging of map was finished.

To get the center of the map you can use `map.getCenter()` function.

To determine when the map finished dragging, you can use some of the `google.maps.Map`'s [User Interface Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) (first example). In your case I would prefer `idle` event instead of e.g. `center_changed` since that get's called more times, but you can choose from the available events yourself.

So your code should probably look something like this:

```
$scope.mapCreated = function(map) {
    $scope.map = map;
    $scope.current_center = null;
    google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, 'idle', function(){
       $scope.current_center = $scope.map.getCenter();
       console.log($scope.current_center.toString()); //this will print out latitude and longitude of map's center after dragging/zooming finished
    });
};
```